# Typescript mapped types not generating correct output

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a project where I want to allow the user to choose specific fields to get from a specific type. Given the following type:

```js
type DataType = {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
  field3?: {
    subField1: number;
    subField2: string;
  };
  field4?: number[];
};
```

I want to convert this type to the following type:

```js
type DataTypeFlags = {
  field1?: boolean;
  field2?: boolean;
  field3?: {
    subField1?: boolean;
    subField2?: boolean;
  };
  field4?: boolean;
};
```

I have come up with the following which mostly works well, but breaks if one of the fields from the original type has a field that is an array:

```js
type Flags<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, any> | undefined ? Flags<T[K]> : boolean;
};

type DataTypeFlags = Flags<DataType>;
// outputs:
// {
//   field1?: boolean; | undefined  // good
//   field2?: boolean; | undefined  // good
//   field3?: {
//     subField1?: boolean | undefined; // good
//     subField2?: boolean | undefined; // good
//   } | undefined;
//   field4?: (boolean | undefined)[] | undefined; // breaks here
// }
```

Why does my `Flags` type not work in the state that it's in? Is there a solution to this or is this a limitation of Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem here is the use of optional types.
One possible solution is to use `NonNullable` wrappers to exclude `undefined` from the given type. Here's an example:

```
type DataType = {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
  field3?: {
    subField1: number;
    subField2: string;
  };
  field4?: number[];
};

type Flages<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [P in keyof T]+?: NonNullable<T[P]> extends Record<string, unknown> ? Flages<NonNullable<T[P]>> : boolean
}


const example: Flages<DataType> = {
  field1: false,
  field3: {
    subField1: false
  },
  field4: true
}
```

PS `+?` modifier will explicitly make a property optional

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeAoKUBmAlhADYAmAjAFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNy4HHkBMNAM7A2hWgHMueIqTIBmAPw0cePIPrMAYr0o0GLdlNXqtOgVGGiJRgL5GZ5ACxK6TVmwDaAXS53s2UEgoTRI4cQhBAB4kKAgAD2AIWjJBKAAlCABjAHs2MkjLMXEAGih6WgBrWmyAd1oAPnqoDBUoDwAFKDEoCogQbPwoJC8AahcAOWzacfoSUOYSCGiOryb4xOTUjJy8gpEi0vKq2oaoBWDQ8KjJ6dn5xeX21aaaZmzsxbhabBt-bBzaMJYnE4IwwIsaCEwhFIvBEChIE0WtwHLoCHASIIIMUUTo5MpuGoNNpZNR0ZiINwbDjpDpHDQRPRKb8gA)

Comment: So this solution should cover all cases.
But just to clarify the array case, note that arrays in TypeScript are also considered objects, and so they match the Record<string, any> type. Therefore, when the Flags type encounters an array field, it tries to apply the Flags type to its elements, which results in an array of booleans, but wrapped in an additional undefined due to the use of the conditional type

Comment: That's a very clean and straightforward solution, I've come across the `+?` modifier before but this is the first time I've had to use it practically. I sometimes forget that an array is considered a special type of object in JS/TS. Just knowing that makes it clear why `(boolean | undefined)[] | undefined` was getting returned in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

What about just handling the use case of arrays ?

```
type Flags<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (any[]|undefined) ? boolean : T[K] extends Record<string, any> | undefined ? Flags<NonNullable<T[K]>> : boolean;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeAoKUBmAlhADYAmAjAFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNy4HHkBMNAM7A2hWgHMueIqTIBmAPw0cePIPrMAYr0o0GLdlNXqtOgVGGiJRgL5GZ5ACxK6TVmwDaAXS53s2UEgoTRI4cUEAHiQoCAAPYAhaMkEoACUIAGMAezYyCMsxcQAaKDhaEAA%20CqgMFSgPAGkoMSgAawgQLPwoJC8aJEavGPjE5KgACjKQbwAfeiSIIloIMgBKKAUoZiyskggyqH7B4YSklPTs3PyRQpKp6pmoebJFsRWN4NDwiIA5LNofvQSKFmHsooMqoctjs9mVfFwAqhYAhkKgQmEUhh0d94IgUJAKhwgA)